# Printing array outside foreach loop

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, scope, printf

basically I just want to print the whole array...when I did it inside of the foreach loop
it prints okay - the whole array. But when I tried to do this outside of the foreach loop it prints only the last element of an array.

**EXPECTED: 000001066**

**RESULT: 066**

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

```
my $var;
foreach (@rows) {
    (my $dump = $_->{WA}) =~ s/\s+$//;
    ($shortdump->{MANDT},$shortdump->{CCCATEGORY},$shortdump->{CCCORACTIV},$shortdump->{CCNOCLIIND}) =
        map { s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; $_ } split(";", $dump);
    my @array = split('', $shortdump->{MANDT}, length($shortdump->{MANDT}));
    $var = join "", @array;
    print @array; #THIS WILL PRINT NORMALLY
}
print "Array: $var"; #PRINT ONLY LAST ELEMENT, NOT WHOLE ARRAY
```

Comment: Please provide us with a self-contained, runnable example that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print out the whole array, you have to accumulate the values.

So instead of using

```
$var = join "", @array;
```

you should use

```
$var = $var . join "", @array;
```

or the shortcut:

```
$var .= join "", @array;
```